# Laravel 5 global middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a route group in my `routes.php` file with the middleware specified like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
        return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
    });
}
```

I am using the [Lucadegasperi Oauth2 Server](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) addon. For its setup, I had to enter the following LucaDegasperi item in the `$middleware` array of the `Kernel.php` file (Kernel class):

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

The `$middlewareGroups` array of the same class is as follows:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
```

What the `OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware` does is that it formats exceptions to JSON responses. Now when I apply the `'middleware' => 'api'` in the route group as shown, the global middlewares dont work. I can say this because the HTML error page shows when exceptions occur. However, when I omit the `'middleware' => 'api'` in the route group, the global middlewares work and I get JSON responses for the errors.

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is due to changes with how Laravel handles exceptions in Middleware from 5.2.7 onwards, as documented in [this ticket I raised](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/641). To fix this you need to alter your Exception handler (as explained in the issue) or await the latest patch from the package.

I've [commmitted a fix to the repository](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/pull/653) which fixes the issue of the changes made to Laravel 5.2, however this has not yet been merged.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add `Authorizer` to `aliases` array?

```
'Authorizer' => LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\Authorizer::class,
```

Because you're using it in:

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
});
```

Comment: Yep. I followed the instructions step by step.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the `Throttle` library ? I don't know because I haven't worked with it. Could you post more info about the error?